# C pipe sends not all of the numbers

Tags: c, fork, pipe

So I have this program where the initial process sends numbers to the child, then the child performs certain operations with numbers and sends them to the next child...
My problem is that where the program has to send the numbers starting from two (2), the first number the child gets is 3. What could the problem be?

Here is my code:

```
void start(int num_of_nums){
if (num_of_nums <= 0) return;
int pipefd[2];
pid_t cpid;

int pipe_res = pipe(pipefd);
if (pipe_res == -1) {
    printf("pipe error in start\n");
    perror("pipe error");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

//create a new process
cpid = fork();

if (cpid == -1) {
    printf("fork error in start\n");
    perror("fork error");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
if (cpid == 0) {    // child
    printf("child in start\n");
    close(pipefd[1]); // close write end
    int num_from_parent = pipefd[0]; //where the number is read
    printf("num from parent is %d\n", num_from_parent); //prints out 3...
    filter(num_from_parent);
} else {            // parent 
    printf("parent in start\n");
    close(pipefd[0]);          // close read end 
    for (int i = 2; i <= num_of_nums + 1; i++){
        write(pipefd[1], &i, sizeof(int)); //WHERE THE NUMBERS ARE SENT
    }
    close(pipefd[1]);
}
```

}
Help would be much appreciated...

Comment: Read the manpage for `pipe()`? The example says you need to `read(pipefd[0])`, not just `printf("%d",pipefd[0])`

Comment: Okay, thank you. I understood it - I did not understand properly what a file descriptor is, and pipefd[0] was a file descriptor, not an actual number.

Comment: Strange, you did the right thing on the writing end...

Comment: Yes, I wrote it right, but then when the child process reads it, it doesn't just get the number by accessing the pipefd[0]. In order to access the first number, I would have to read it from the file descriptor (i.e. read(pipefd[0], &number, sizeof(int))).

Comment: I mean.. yes, exactly what you said in the first comment =)

Comment: Keep in mind that a single `read/write` call may read/write only part of the content. You need to retry until all is read/written or an error occurs. Look at [read_pid/write_pid functions](https://gist.github.com/zed/7623724)